# Socket connection not recognising all clients/connections

Tags: node.js, sockets

So far sockets is working as expected. On my server I have:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(1923);

// after an action
io.sockets.emit('items', data);
```

Then on the client side:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1923');
socket.on('items', (items) => {
  // do stuff with items
});
```

Now this is working nicely when I'm on my own machine. As soon as different devices open the site it only updates on the browsers on my computer.

*Computer*

- Firefox has the site open
- Chrome too

*Mobile*

- Site is open on Chrome for mobile

Now after an action takes place, only the sites on the computer gets updated and not my new device. Checking the connections it also only recognises `clientsCount: 2`. (instead of 3)

The site is open on three separate browsers. What am I doing wrong for this to be happening?

*(sidenote: I've tried the same with a second computer, it's not specific to the mobile device.)*

Comment: This client code `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1923');` won't work anywhere except on the same computer as the server is on.   `localhost` is, by definition`, the local computer and only the local computer.  You will need to connect by IP address or by DNS name.

Comment: If I connect on my phone or other PC I'm in the same WIFI and access the page by `192.168.0.10:8080`. So I don't think that should be the issue

Comment: Well, that isn't what the code in your question shows and isn't even the same port.  How are we to know what your client code looks like?  Clearly you have a connection issue.  You need to debug the client and see if it thinks it is actually connecting or log whatever error it shows.  You can try logging `socket.on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)});`

Comment: thank you for your advice! True about the port. The one I posted in the comment is where my app is running. The socket connection is through the `:1923` port.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct! the connection is established with the other device if I connect with `const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.10:1923');` instead of `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1923');`. The localhost really **only** works on my machine and if it's a (local) IP address the connection gets established. Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it seemed to have solved your issue...

This client code:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1923');
```

won't work anywhere except on the same computer as the server is on. localhost is, by definition`, the local computer and only the local computer. You will need to connect by IP address or by DNS name.

Perhaps you want this:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.10:1923');
```